# Application of Rolle's theorem? Establish existence of $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f(c)+f'(c)=f(c)f'(c)$

Tags: real-analysis, rolles-theorem

*Following [my question on Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26112/best-way-to-revive-a-question-which-does-not-abide-by-the-math-se-rules), I post this as a new question; it was originally [asked by Gmgfg](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2205750/prove-a-equality-of-functions), and closed due to the lack of context, background, and shown  effort.*

> Let $f\colon[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ with $f(a)=f(b)=0$. Show that there exists $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)+f(c)=f(c)f'(c)$.

Now, given the assumptions this looks like it should be a straightforward application of Rolle's theorem. However:

- as far as I can tell there is no simple auxiliary function $\Phi$ such that $\Phi'= f+f'-f\cdot f'$ to which one could apply Rolle's theorem. *(If there is one, I failed to find it.)*
- indeed, while the RHS could come from $\left(\frac{f^2}{2}\right)'$; it's mostly the LHS which looks difficult to handle *(and there is no clear advantage I can see in introducing an antiderivative $F$ of $f$ to have it be $(F+f)'$).*

I verified the statement for some functions I could think of, such as $x\mapsto x(1-x)$ and $x\mapsto \sin \pi x$ on $[a,b]=[0,1]$. So, in that regard, it seems to hold at least against basic sanity checks.

*However*, what bothers me is the lack of "homogeneity." Usually, in things like that I'm used to saying that "without loss of generality, one can assume $[a,b]=[0,1]$." It does not appear to be the case here: if, given $f$, one defines $g\colon[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ by $g(x) = f((b-a)x+a)$, finding $c\in(0,1)$ such that $g'(c)+g(c)=g(c)g'(c)$ does not directly yield $c'$ such that $f'(c')+f(c')=f(c')f'(c')$ (but rather would give $c'$ such that $f'(c')+(b-a)f(c')=f(c')f'(c')$, if I'm not mistaken).

> So, in short: is it true? And how to prove or disprove it — I'm at a loss, and embarrassed about it.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Let
$$ g(x) = f(x)e^{x-f(x)}. $$
Then $g(a) = g(b) = 0$ since $f(a)=f(b)=0$, so $g'(c) = 0$ for some $c\in(a,b)$. However,
$$ g'(x) = f'(x)e^{x-f(x)} + f(x)e^{x-f(x)}(1-f'(x)) = e^{x-f(x)}(f'(x)+f(x)-f(x)f'(x)),$$
so $g'(c) = 0\implies f'(c)+f(c)-f(c)f'(c) = 0$, i.e. $f'(c)+f(c) = f(c)f'(c)$.

Comment: Wow, this was fast -- also, this auxiliary function does look really contrived to me. Any intuition as to how you came up with it?

Comment: I guess what you could do is consider something of the form $f(x) e^{g(x)} $ and see what function $g$ does the trick. Following this idea gives $g'(x)  = 1-f'(x)$ in this case.

Comment: @ClementC. essentially I was trying to solve $f'+f = ff'$ via integrating factors to get the right function that derived correctly. So I first multiplied by $e^x$ on both sides to get $y'$ on the LHS, where $y(x) = e^xf(x)$. But then I noticed that the RHS was just $y(x)f'(x)$, and the integrating factor for $y'-f'y$ is $e^{-f(x)}$. That suggested I should consider $e^{-f(x)}y(x) = e^{-f(x)}e^xf(x) = f(x)e^{x-f(x)}$.

Comment: @JoeyZou Great. Thank you!

Comment: your comment is more important than the answer. +1 for both the comment and the answer.