# A different approach to solve the problem related to LMVT

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Let $f (x) $ be a function satisfying all the conditions of Lagrange's MVT in [a-1,a+1]. Then prove that for $x\in [a-1,a+1] $  $$f (a+1)-2f (a)+f (a-1)=f'(a+k)-f'(a-k)$$ where $k\in (0,1) $ .$$\text {Approach} $$. Now with some experience I predicted that let $F (x)=f (x)-f (x-1) $ using LMVT in $[a,a+1] $ as $f(x) $ is following the conditions in $[a-1,a+1] $  we have $f (a+1)-2f (a)+f (a-1)=f'(a+k)+f'(a+k-1) $ but now heres a catch  as we are getting $a+k-1$ instead of $a-k $ in the last bracket  I'm not finding a way to complete it correctly.

Comment: What does LMVT refer to?

Comment: Lagrange's MVT.

Comment: Your approach should give you the expression $f'(a+k) - f'(a+k-1)$. This gives a further evidence of typo in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x) =f(a+x) + f(a-x) $ for $x\in[0,1]$. Then by mean value theorem we have $g(1)-g(0)=g'(k)$ for some $k\in(0,1)$. This means that $$f(a+1)-2f(a)+f(a-1)=f'(a+k)-f'(a-k)$$ I suspect a typo in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I wanted to ask how can someone come up with such substitutions ? I mean they arent very intuitive as such . Will this build only by solving problems or is there any other trick?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: there are a few tricks in any trade (which gives birth to the phrase "tricks of the trade") but overall their importance pales in comparison to the importance of the fundamentals. For this example I proceeded by integrating the expression $f'(a+k) - f'(a-k) $ with respect to $k$ to get $f(a+k) +f(a-k) $ and the function $g(x) $ was thus obtained. I will post you a link to another question where this integration thing is more difficult.

Comment: Thanks for replying:).

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: see this similar but significantly difficult question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2211094/72031 here it is simply impossible to guess the function. One of the answers explains the basic idea in the comments.